# AspectJ: intercept constructor when method reference is used

Tags: java, java-8, aspectj

For normal contructor calls with `new` I use

```
pointcut replaceableNew() : call((@Replaceable *).new(..));

Object around() : replaceableNew() {
        Constructor<?> constructor = ((ConstructorSignature) thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature()).getConstructor ;
        Class<?> declaringClass = constructor.getDeclaringClass(); 
        if (!Registry.getInstance().isReplaced(declaringClass))  {
            return proceed() ;
        }
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
        Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
        return Registry.getInstance().create(declaringClass, parameterTypes, args); // creates some sub-class of declaring class
    }
```

but this does not work when contructor is passed as method references.

`Stream.of(1,2).map(SomeReplaceable::new) ...`

Workaround for instance method references (with "*lambda*" ) does not work.

`execution((@Replaceable *).new(..))` pointcut  does not allow to replace the returned object.

Maybe some combination of `call(* *(..))` and `execution(...` above could work, but this way we will advice too much calls and also will create and discard unneccessary replaceable instances. Looks ugly.

Any other ideas?

Comment: That is an interesting question, but in order to answer it I either have to create my own application classes for testing and imagine what the registry does, or you provide something I can copy, compile, run and analyse. It is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I think I have a pretty good idea what your code does, but actually do not feel so inclined to write all the code to make your aspect work and the problem reproducible. So please help me to help you. Thank you.

Comment: In order to avoid making this yet another instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898), I also kindly ask you to not just explain **how** you want to solve your problem but also **what** you are trying to achieve. Is this some kind of test mock tool you are developing? But that would not work for final classes.

Comment: This is not mocking tool. This is a way to customize some standard product by injecting different implementation of classes - mostly some data models. It works fine for many years just not in this case.

Comment: Theoretically AspectJ could support replacing of method references by adjusting `invokedynamic` instruction that calls lambda factory to replace constructor reference with  synthentic static method with the similar signature. In synthentic method it may just call referenced constructor - then `call` pointcut will work. But ApsectJ still does not support this. This is not fatal for our framework - we can catch such situations in our code analyzer and issue a warning, that ctr references can not be used for such classes.

Comment: Sorry, my (correct) answer is not explaining what AspectJ could do in theory but what it can do it practice. So please accept the answer anyway, even though you do not like the reality. BTW, just yesterday there was an announcement on the AspectJ users mailing list that finally they moved their main repository from a Git repository somewhere at Eclipse to GitHub (until yesterday only a mirror) and the tickets to GitHub issues. So now it is easier than before to contribute PRs or create issues. Maybe this is worth a question on the ML first, then an issue if the maintainer agrees.

Comment: You did not answer the question. I was asking what other variants are possible. Now I know another one - replacing the reference (the object constructed from construtor reference), though reflection is complicated.

Comment: I think I did answer the question. Let's recapitulate, shall we? You asked a question tagged _aspectj_, posted and talked about AspectJ code **only** and then asked: _"Any other ideas?"_ Nowhere did you indicate that you wanted to talk about any ideas **outside** of AspectJ. And now you say I didn't answer your question. How about asking your question then next time instead of talking about something else? My magical crystal globe for reading your mind is broken, I am afraid.

Comment: I am sorry, that your globe is broken. My previous comment was about AspectJ.

Comment: Fine. But talk is cheap. If you have an AspectJ-based solution, please write your own answer here including [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so the community you were asking for help gets something in return and can profit from your new knowledge. Present your own solution in a comprehensive and reproducible way. You can then even accept your own answer and thus close the question. But please don't just complain about my answer, present something better. I would be interested in learning from you, too. 

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe some combination of `call(* *(..))` and `execution(..)` above could work

No, it will not, because there simply is no `call()` joinpoint to intercept for AspectJ when using method references. The same is true for reflective constructor calls.

Thus, your idea will only work for simple cases, i.e. when there is a normal constructor call you can intercept. As you already noticed, you cannot directly replace the instance generated by a constructor, not even with low level byte code engineering frameworks such as ASM or BCEL or higher level ones like Javassist or ByteBuddy - simply because the JVM does not allow it. The best you can do with such frameworks is to transform the constructor code such that it skips object initialisation and directly calls the super constructor with dummy arguments (all super constructors also have to be instrumented in order to skip initialisation, BTW).

Besides, your aspect, even if it was possible to replace objects returned by `execution(*.new(..))`, would have to take care of excluding `this()` and `super()` calls, make sure to do the right thing if a subclass of the annotated class is being instantiated etc.

The whole idea just does not work. Sorry to destroy your dream (I also used to have this idea many years ago), but these are the facts.

Coming back to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898): I am asking you again to rather describe **what** you want to achieve, not to describe **how** you think this ought to be done technically. What is your use case? Which problem are you trying to solve?